# Dafny export clause in a module

Tags: module, export, dafny

```
module A {
    export S reveals f
    export M provides g

    function f (x:int):int
    {x+1}

    function g (x:int):int
    {x-1}

}

module B {
    import opened A`{S,M}

    //export K reveals k

    //export K provides k

    function k (x:int):int
        requires f(x) == 0
    {x*2}

}
```

Activating any of the commented export clauses in module B makes the imported function f to be unknown for module B. Some help?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit confusing, or at least subtle. Uncommenting either of the two `export K ...` declarations produces the following two errors:

```
This export set is not consistent: K

Raised while checking export set K: unresolved identifier: f
```

Let me explain. I will focus on the `export K provides k` declaration; the other is similar.

By declaring an export set, a module makes available a subset of its declarations to the module's importers. The `provides` clause puts the "signature" of a declaration into the export set, and a `reveals` clause puts both the "signature" and the "body" of the declaration into the export set. For a function, the "signature" of the declaration includes the function's type signature as well as the function's specification. So, the `provides k` clause in your example essentially says to export the following portion of the declaration of `k`:

```
function k (x:int):int requires f(x) == 0
```

The relevant thing to notice here is that this portion of the declaration also mentions `f`. (This is also true for the export declaration with `reveal k`.)

An export set has to be *self consistent*. This means that everything mentioned in the exported declarations (more precisely, the exported portions--"signature" or "signature + body"--of the exported declarations) must make sense separately. In particular, this means that every symbol that is mentioned in the portions that are exported (here, the mention of `f` in the precondition of `k`) must also be part of the export set.

So, the problem is that you're trying to export `k` but not `f`. If `f` were declared in module `B`, you would know what to do: just add `f` to a `provides` clause of your export set. But in your case, `f` is declared in module `A`, not in `B`. This seems like a problem, because an export set in module `B` is only allowed to export symbols defined in `B`.

The problem has a simple solution. To explain it more clearly, let me temporarily change your module `B` a little:

```
module B {
  import A = A`S
  export K provides k
  function k (x:int):int requires A.f(x) == 0 {x*2}
}
```

Here, I'm importing only `` A`S `` (not `` A`M ``), I'm explicitly showing the local name for `` A`S `` (namely, `A`), and I have omitted the `opened` keyword. Since I omitted the `opened` keyword, I also had to qualify the mention of `f` in `k`'s specification (writing `A.f` instead of just `f`).

Okay, in this module `B`, export set `K` is still not consistent, because it tries to provide `k` without providing `A.f`. More precisely, the second error message now says that `A` is unresolved. This is good, because (the local name) `A` is declared in `B`, which means we can export it. To solve this problem, simply add `provides A` to the export set:

```
export K provides k, A
```

This makes export set `K` consistent, because every symbol mentioned in the ("signature" portion of the) declaration of `k` is visible. It is not necessary for `K` to export `f` directly, because `f` is mentioned by `.f` as a member of `A`, and `A` is exported.

Let's work our way back to your example, in four steps.

As a first step, let's change my `import` declaration to import both of `A`'s export sets, `S` and `M`:

```
import A = A`{S,M}
```

Here, I'm still showing the local name `A` explicitly.

As a second step, let's add back the `opened` keyword:

```
import opened A = A`{S,M}
```

This makes it possible to refer to the imported declarations either as qualified (like `A.f`) or as unqualified (just `f`).

As a third step, let's make use of the fact that, inside `B`, we can refer to `f` as unqualified:

```
function k (x:int):int requires f(x) == 0 {x*2}
```

As a fourth and final step to get back to your example, let's omit the explicit local name `A` in the `import` declaration. The default local name is the same as the module being imported, namely `A`.  Now, we have the following error-free program:

```
module B {
  import opened A`{S,M}
  export K provides k, A
  function k (x:int):int requires f(x) == 0 {x*2}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Rustan